# Что не так со static (или со мной)

Tags: python, flask

Всех приветствую. Начал создавать веб-приложение, используя Flask. Если вкратце о проблеме, то я создал папку `static` и в ней `style.css` с кодом

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Как и ожидалось, после запуска сервера задний план страницы окрасился в красный. Затем я удалил папку static. Перезапустил сервер, и для меня стало неожиданностью, что страница всё ещё красная.

Структура приложения следующая

```
flask_app/
    /app
        /templates
            index.html
        [здесь был /static]
        views.py
        __init__.py
    /env # виртуальная среда
        ...
    runner.py
```

Сам сервер запускаю командой `python runner.py runserver`, предварительно запустив виртуальную среду.

Файл `index.html`. Прошу обратить внимание, что файла `style.css` больше не существует, а сервер его как-то находит. Файл где-то продолжает храниться? Потому что, даже создавая новый static/style.css, я сталкиваюсь с тем, что новые стили не применяются и страница тупа продолжает быть красной.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    chto?
</body>
</html>
```

Файл `runner.py`

```
from app import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Файл `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


from . import views
```

Файл `views.py`

```
from app import app

import os
import pickle


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте в браузере обновить страницу через `Ctrl + F5` (чтобы сбросился кэш).

Comment: или ctrl + shift + del

Comment: @nomnoms12, `Ctrl + F5` помогло. Спасибо большоё!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422901/4794368 `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0` [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT)

Comment: что-то не пойму, откуда взялся `runserver` где `flask_script`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большинство браузеров кэширует статические файлы (в том числе CSS), чтобы обновление страницы происходило быстрее.

Чтобы сбросить кэш для текущей страницы, можно использовать сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (в Windows и Linux) и <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> в macOS .